# how to use image captha in mvc 6 .net core 5?

Tags: asp.net, bitmap, asp.net-core-mvc

i want to know how to use image drawing in  mvc 6 .net core 5 GDi+ ?? reference
systeam.drawing library not use in .net core 5  i want to use this code by .net core 5

```
private static Bitmap GenerateRandomCaptchaImage(string text)
{
    var bitmap = new Bitmap(200, 150);
    var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

    var pen = new Pen(Color.Yellow);
    var rect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 150);
    var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);

   g.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
   g.FillRectangle(brush, rect);           
   g.DrawString(text, new Font("Georgia", 20), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 10, 50);

   DrawRandomLines(g);

    g.Dispose();
    return bitmap;
}

private static System.Drawing.Point[] GetRandomPoints()
{
    var rand = new Random();

    System.Drawing.Point[] points = { new System.Drawing.Point(rand.Next(10, 150), rand.Next(10, 150)), new System.Drawing.Point(rand.Next(10, 100), rand.Next(10, 100)) };

    return points;
}

private static void DrawRandomLines(Graphics g)
{
    SolidBrush green = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        g.DrawLines(new Pen(green, 2), GetRandomPoints());
    }
}
```

Comment: You are implementing the `IDisposable` pattern incorrectly on your `g` variable. You must either put `g.Dispose()` into a `finally` block, or remove the `g.Dispose()` call and wrap `g` in a [using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Comment: thanks for help , my problem is i cant build Solution for e.x Pen is not working in .net Core 5

Comment: Yes, I know that doesn't solve your problem. But it's going to cause you further headaches down the line if you don't implement the `IDisposable` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

there is (currently?) no full support in solution for using `system.drawing` in .net Core.
Instead try using the  open source System.Drawing implementation of Mono.

Which is the System.Drawing replaement?
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/3634

further readings:
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/5921